# Read hex from file matlab

Tags: matlab, char, hex

### What I have

A **txt file** like:

```
D091B
E7E1F
20823
...
```

### What I need

To read them and store them like char, just **as they are in the file**: **N** (don't knot how many) **lines**, with its 5 characters (**5 columns**) at each one.

### What have I tried

```
fichero = fopen('PS.txt','r');
sizeDatos = [[] 5];  % Several Options, read below

resultados=fscanf(fichero, '%s', sizeDatos);  % Here too

fclose(fichero);
```

I've tried with the snippet above, to read my txt file. However, I didn't manage to get it. Most I've obtained is, using:

```
sizeDatos = [1 Inf];
```

So I got all my hex characters into an array, with no spaces.

As you can see, I've tried several optios changing fscanf size parameter, as well as trying to say into the format chain that it should recognize new lines by using `\n` for example. None of them have worked for me.

Any idea about how can I get it? I've readed [fscanf](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#bt_vmbb-1) page from documentation, but it didn't inspire me to make anything different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is using `textscan` and convert it to a cell array.

```
fileId = fopen('PS.txt');
C = textscan(fileId, '%s');
```

Now to show the content of cell you can use

```
celldisp(C)
```

Or you can convert it to other types.

Don't forget to close your file after using it.